# Experimenting with a Siri Remote

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, siri-remote

I have an Apple Siri Remote (gen 3). I am trying to use it with an older iMac (late 2013). It should be noted that this iMac does not have the IR sensor and cannot use the older remotes.

I've used the Bluetooth Explorer application from the Additional Tools for Xcode package, and within its various (confusing) panels and windows, I've managed to see that I can determine the battery level. In addition to that, when I hold the microphone button on the remote, one of the graph plotting windows does show that it sends a tremendous amount of bluetooth data (as one would expect).

Are there any tools, command-line or otherwise, that would be able to intercept bluetooth packets from this device, and hopefully parse those? The buttons themselves seem to be exposed as a plain HID device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Apple Siri Remote third generation (model A2854), you can

- update your iMac 2013 to macOS Ventura 13.x using [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/)*
- install the commercial tool BetterTouchTool
- add the Siri remote as a trigger and configure the buttons as needed. [image: BetterTouchTool configuration]

Note: I am not affiliated with the developer but I use this tool extensively since 2012, also with Siri Remotes.

**edit: The original answer was 'macOS Catalina 10.15', which does not support the Siri remote A2854. For this, macOS Ventura 13.x is needed. Officially it cannot be installed on an iMac14,1/14,2/14,3 (iMac late 2013), but with the tool 'OpenCore Legacy Patcher' all iMac hardware features are supported.

Comment: I haven't checked out this particular tool, but the others I did install and check all claimed minimum of Big Sur to make the remote work. Are you certain Catalina is sufficient? I'd be willing to upgrade for that. $10 seems reasonable.

Comment: Don't spend any money after installing it. You should be able to use the trial. Also, you might need to download an older version from the website (the application _should_ tell you the latest compatible version after installing it).

Comment: Upgraded to Catalina... was a little bit of a nail-biting experience. I have the latest BTT, though I know you suggested I might have to find an earlier one. I can pair the remote as before, but it shows up as a generic device in Bluetooth settings. BTT does not seem to recognize that the remove is paired.

Comment: According to the developer of BTT, this remote would require Ventura to work.

Comment: @JohnO Oh no, what a bummer. Thank you for sharing your result and experience. If the remote requires macOS 13.x, can you get a confirmation from the dev if installing Ventura on your iMac iMac14,1/14,2/14,3 using OpenCore Legacy Patcher would make it work? https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html#imac

Comment: I've actually just upgraded to Ventura... it was a sphincter-clenching experience. I swore it was in a boot-loop installing, it must have restarted at least 8 times. But it's up and running, and pretty snappy too. I'm surprised. I have it working with BTT now, though all I've managed to figure out is how to launch Plex with the tv button. Will take awhile to get the rest worked out... I don't think I need to return the remote for a refund now. Shows promise.

Comment: I am very glad it's working for you and that you can control you iMac now conveniently with the current Siri Remote. :) I think BTT might be intimidating in the beginning but at the same time very powerful if after trying to see how it works